# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6 JAVA, ARRAY

Tags: java, arrays

I realize this is an unbelievably common issue and have looked very very thoroughly but have had no luck! It seems I am having an outOfBounds Exception issue. My code is as follows wuth errors just after! Thanks again :)

UPDATE:
Thanks for all of your many fast responses. Although it says there's an issue with Analysis Panel, I didn't know exactly if this was the cause as I have other classes which use it with no issues! But below is the other code. Thanks again!

```
public class AnalysisPanel extends JPanel {

private JTextArea overview_text = GuiComponentGenerator.getJTextArea("");

private JTextArea csv_text = GuiComponentGenerator.getJTextArea("");

private JComboBox analyser_choices;

private String[] analyser_class_names;

private LinkedHashMap<String, ImageAnalysis> analyser_outputs = new LinkedHashMap();

private JTextField[] weka_directory_texts;

private JTextField[] weka_tag_texts;

private JTextField weka_output_file_path_text = GuiComponentGenerator
        .getJTextField("");

private JTextField weka_relation_text = GuiComponentGenerator
        .getJTextField("");

public AnalysisPanel() {
    GuiComponentGenerator.setLook(this);
    analyser_class_names = ResourceAndClassDirectories
            .getClassNamesInDirectory(ResourceAndClassDirectories.IMAGE_ANALYSERS_CLASS_STEM);
    ArrayList<String> choices = new ArrayList(
            Arrays.asList(analyser_class_names));
    choices.add(0, "All");
    analyser_choices = GuiComponentGenerator.getJComboBox(choices);
    analyser_choices.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            updateTextBoxes();
        }
    });
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(BorderLayout.NORTH,
            GuiComponentGenerator.getJPanel(analyser_choices));
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, getTextsPanel());
    add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, getWekaPanel());
}

private JPanel getWekaPanel() {
    JPanel weka_panel = GuiComponentGenerator.getJPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel details_panel = GuiComponentGenerator.getJPanel(new GridLayout(
            6, 1));

    JPanel top_panel = GuiComponentGenerator
            .getJPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    JPanel left_top_panel = GuiComponentGenerator.getJPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel right_top_panel = GuiComponentGenerator.getJPanel(new BorderLayout());
    left_top_panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST, GuiComponentGenerator.getJLabel("Relation:"));
    left_top_panel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, weka_relation_text);
    right_top_panel.add(BorderLayout.WEST, GuiComponentGenerator.getJLabel("Output to:"));
    right_top_panel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, weka_output_file_path_text);
    top_panel.add(left_top_panel);
    top_panel.add(right_top_panel);
    weka_panel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, top_panel);

    weka_directory_texts = new JTextField[5];
    weka_tag_texts = new JTextField[5];

    JPanel labels_panel = GuiComponentGenerator.getJPanel(new GridLayout(1,
            2));
    labels_panel.add(GuiComponentGenerator.getCentreAlignedJLabel("Tag"));
    labels_panel.add(GuiComponentGenerator
            .getCentreAlignedJLabel("Image directory"));
    details_panel.add(labels_panel);
    for (int pos = 0; pos < 5; pos++)
        details_panel.add(getDetailsPanel(pos));

    weka_panel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, top_panel);
    weka_panel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, details_panel);
    JPanel weka_bordered_panel = GuiComponentGenerator
            .getLeftBorderedJPanel(weka_panel, "Weka");
    return weka_bordered_panel;
}

private JPanel getDetailsPanel(int pos) {
    JPanel details_panel = GuiComponentGenerator.getJPanel(new GridLayout(
            1, 2));

    final JTextField weka_directory_text = GuiComponentGenerator
            .getJTextField("");
    JTextField weka_tag_text = GuiComponentGenerator.getJTextField("");

    weka_directory_texts[pos] = weka_directory_text;
    weka_tag_texts[pos] = weka_tag_text;

    JPanel right_panel = GuiComponentGenerator
            .getJPanel(new BorderLayout());
    right_panel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, weka_directory_text);

    JButton choose_directory_button = GuiComponentGenerator
            .getJButton(GuiComponentGenerator.FILE_DIALOG_ICON);
    right_panel.add(BorderLayout.EAST, choose_directory_button);

    choose_directory_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            File directory = FileChooserDialog.getFile(
                    ResourceAndClassDirectories.SOURCE_DIRECTORY, "", true);
            if (directory != null)
                weka_directory_text.setText(directory.getPath());
        }
    });

    details_panel.add(weka_tag_text);
    details_panel.add(right_panel);

    return details_panel;
}

public String[] getWekaRunDetails() {
    String[] wrd = { weka_relation_text.getText(),
            weka_output_file_path_text.getText() };
    return wrd;
}

public ArrayList<String[]> getWekaImageDetails() {
    ArrayList<String[]> image_details = new ArrayList();
    for (int pos = 0; pos < 5; pos++) {
        String[] details = { weka_directory_texts[pos].getText(),
                weka_tag_texts[pos].getText() };
        image_details.add(details);
    }
    return image_details;
}

private JPanel getTextsPanel() {
    JPanel texts_panel = GuiComponentGenerator
            .getJPanel(new BorderLayout());
    csv_text.setRows(3);
    csv_text.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    texts_panel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, GuiComponentGenerator
            .getLeftBorderedJPanel(
                    GuiComponentGenerator.getJScrollPane(csv_text), "CSV"));
    texts_panel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, GuiComponentGenerator
            .getLeftBorderedJPanel(
                    GuiComponentGenerator.getJScrollPane(overview_text),
                    "Overview"));
    return texts_panel;
}

public String getChosenImageAnalyser() {
    return (String) analyser_choices.getSelectedItem();
}

public void performAnalyses(final TaggedBufferedImage tbi) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            analyser_outputs.clear();
            String choice = (String) analyser_choices.getSelectedItem();
            csv_text.setText("");
            if (choice.equals("All")) {
                for (String analyser_class_name : analyser_class_names)
                    performAnalysis(analyser_class_name, tbi);
            } else
                performAnalysis(choice, tbi);
            updateTextBoxes();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

private void updateTextBoxes() {
    String overview = "";
    String csv_headings = "|";
    String csv_values = "|";
    String choice = (String) analyser_choices.getSelectedItem();
    for (String analyser_class_name : analyser_class_names) {
        if (choice.equals("All") || choice.equals(analyser_class_name)) {
            ImageAnalysis image_analysis = analyser_outputs
                    .get(analyser_class_name);
            if (image_analysis != null) {
                overview += analyser_class_name + "\n\n"
                        + image_analysis.overview + "\n-----------------\n";
                System.out.println("In Analysis Panel: image analsis csv headings " + image_analysis.csv_headings.size());
                for (int pos = 0; pos < image_analysis.csv_headings.size(); pos++) {
                    String heading = image_analysis.csv_headings.get(pos);
                    String value = image_analysis.csv_values.get(pos);
                    while (heading.length() < value.length())
                        heading += " ";
                    while (value.length() < heading.length())
                        value += " ";
                    csv_values += value + "|";
                    csv_headings += heading + "|";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    overview_text.setText(overview);
    csv_text.setText(csv_headings + "\n" + csv_values);
}

private void performAnalysis(String analyser_class_name,
        TaggedBufferedImage tbi) {
    try {
        overview_text.setText("Analysing " + analyser_class_name);
        Class c = Class
                .forName(ResourceAndClassDirectories.IMAGE_ANALYSERS_CLASS_STEM
                        + "." + analyser_class_name);
        ImageAnalyserInterface analyser = (ImageAnalyserInterface) c
                .newInstance();
        ImageAnalysis image_analysis = analyser.analyseImage(tbi);
        analyser_outputs.put(analyser_class_name, image_analysis);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Update: Now working, although the issue was in the below, it needed to be changed in the Colour file itself!

Thanks all :)

Comment: That's a lot of code. Where do you go past the end? Are you taking into account that Java arrays are 0-based? Is it that pp1 + 1 line?

Comment: Why are all your loops 1-indexed in the first place?

Comment: Which line is it that actually triggers the exception? The error message refers to line numbers but we can't see those.

Comment: Is it just me? The code you post is not in the Stacktrace (the problem seems to be in the method "updateTextBoxes" in Analysispanel) - or am i completely wrong?

Comment: When the exception's stack trace says 'at       sepia.designers.analysis_designer.gui.AnalysisPanel.updateTextBoxes(AnalysisPanel.java:207)' then you should look in exactly that place. You also should include the affected code line in your question here to help us answer it.

Comment: Thanks all! I have added my code for the updateTextBoxes etc! Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there are 6 elements in the array, then index **5** will be the final index, as it is zero indexed - that is, 0,1,2,3,4,5 is 6 elements

Answer (score 9):

Well based on the title you are trying to access index 6 in an array of size 6.  This is not possible since arrays in Java run from index 0 to size-1.

Your max possible index is therefore 5 in an array of size 6.

Comment: yes I believe that is fine to start running the array from 1-6, and when referencing the array i.e. array[pos -1] this deals with it! I think it just personal preference! but thank you

Comment: Well your loop can run from 1 - size if you like, as long as when you access the array you are accessing it as a 0 based array.